# Geometry in Derived Column SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial, ssis

I have a Spatial file (*.shp) with 30 million records which I am reading using SSIS and has a column POINT(Lat,long).

While reading the file I want to convert this column(POINT) into Geometry using STGeomFromText. I can't use this function in derived column or Script so I have to update the column using the below sql.

```
Update table
set mygeom_Column = geometry:STGeomFromText(Point,0);
```

Is there any way I can directly convert the column into geometry while reading? Or use some function in Derived column to convert into Geometry?

Answer (score 2):

SSIS (up to 2012) does not support geometry.  Please vote for this feature here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/729618/sql-server-2012-integration-services-still-doesnt-support-spatial-datatypes-in-the-data-flow

Answer (score 0):

no as far as i know you can't do that in SSIS. SSIS is only use to copy large data and it does this very fast. In terms of logics SQL is faster. So the faster way is to use the update into SQL